# Change commerce kickstart admin toolbar logo

Tags: 7, commerce

Hello I want to change the logo of the admin toolbar of commerce kickstart how to do it I cannot find any .tpl with that piece of code for chage that logo

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ho it was easy, just add a css class in your subtheme css with the class

```
body.toolbar #toolbar-home a span
```

from there you can change the background image

Answer (score 0):

Your self-answer will only work if you are using the Overlay module.  If you aren't, you can go to profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/commerce_kickstart/commerce_kickstart_menus/images and overwrite the logo-menu.png image with another 130x40px sized one.

If you want to change anything else in the toolbar (logo size, colors, etc...), that's also the module to look at.

Comment: Do not forget: Your logo get's overwritten on every Commerce Update. You have to re-apply those changes.