# Commerce Kickstart 2 change admin toolbar logo

Tags: commerce

In admin/appearance/settings/commerce_kickstart_admin, in section Logo image settings, there is an option to change default logo of admin. You can upload a new logo. But the new logo doesn't appear in admin toolbar.

In Commerce Kickstart 2 how to change the admin toolbar logo?

Comment: Is this not maybe a duplicate of this question? : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120839/change-commerce-kickstart-admin-toolbar-logo

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had seen this link, but didn't understand what to do. The class that he suggest to put in subtheme css is empty. It is weird changing logo with UI in Commerce Kickstart 2 doesn't work. If you can explain me better?